# I am getting error at Conn in the last line saying that "Unreachable code detected"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting error at Conn in the last line saying that "Unreachable code detected". Why?

```
public string insertFileDetails(string insert_osvsrdetails, Hashtable osvsr)
{
    Conn = Connect();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_osvsrdetails, Conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //// add out put parameter////
    SqlParameter msg = cmd.Parameters.Add("@msg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    msg.Size = 50;
    msg.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    /////////////// add input parameter///////////
    IDictionaryEnumerator myEnumerator = osvsr.GetEnumerator();
    while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + (myEnumerator.Key).ToString(), myEnumerator.Value);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + (myEnumerator.Key).ToString(), myEnumerator.Value.ToString().ToUpper()));
    }

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    strReturn = cmd.Parameters["@msg"].Value.ToString();
    return strReturn;
    Conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to close connexion befor return

```
Conn.Close();
return strReturn;
```

or you can use try .. finally

```
try
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_osvsrdetails, Conn);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   //// add out put parameter////
   SqlParameter msg = cmd.Parameters.Add("@msg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
   msg.Size = 50;
   msg.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

   /////////////// add input parameter///////////
   IDictionaryEnumerator myEnumerator = osvsr.GetEnumerator();
   while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
   {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + (myEnumerator.Key).ToString(), myEnumerator.Value);
      //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + (myEnumerator.Key).ToString(), myEnumerator.Value.ToString().ToUpper()));
   }

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   strReturn = cmd.Parameters["@msg"].Value.ToString();
   return strReturn;
}
finally
{
   Conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call methods after you've returned from the method. Move `Conn.Close();` above `return strReturn;` to close the connection before returning.

Answer (score 0):

put this Conn.Close(); line before the return statement

Answer (score 0):

Close connection before return statement

```
 Conn.Close();
 return strReturn;
```